# Is scan code the same on all keyboards

Tags: layout, keyboard, constants

I got problem when one of my customer complains about they use azerty keyboard and they can't use my product. So I decide to use scan code instead of virtual key. I found the function [MapVirtualKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646306(v=vs.85).aspx) is really useful for me to achieve that. But in some situation, I don't want to use MapVirtualKey function but use the number itself, like {if(isKeyDown[30])return 'A';} but I go around the internet and realize that some source tell that their keyboard scan code is not like mine, like in this image 
[image: Not like my keyboard]
I don't understand it, why it's different from my keyboard's scan code, and even different from this [MS scan code table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374(v=vs.60).aspx)

So I really wonder, Is it safe to use

```
if (isDownNow[48])
    return 'B';
```

instead of

```
if (isDownNow[MapVirtualKey('B', MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC)])
    return 'B';
```

Thank you for reading :)

**Edit:**
I think I have a solution for the problem above, instead of call MapVirtualKey every time, I will store the map in an array. But new problem comes up.
I don't have a azerty keyboard so I can't test this, I only have a qwerty keyboard, so I got confuse on this problem: 
I got this function to store my map.

```
void MapKeyData()
{
 for (int i = 0; i < KEYS_SIZE; i++)//KEYS_SIZE=255
   mapKey[i] = MapVirtualKey(i, MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC);//mapKey is unsigned char array
}
```

[image: qwerty vs azerty]
But I want the Z in normal keyboard (qwerty keyboard) map with the W in azerty keyboard. But as the function MapKeyData above, I think the Z in qwerty keyboard still map with the Z in azerty keyboard which is definitely not my purpose, I want to keep the keyboard layout, not the key itself. But as I said, I don't know if the scan code is the same on every keyboard as the first picture show that the keycode different from my scan code.

Thank for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, scan code is the same on all keyboard layout. I've tested this fact by changing my keyboard layout to other layout [with windows settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2brLeGFqQ8).

So to solve the different keyboard layout across PCs, I created an array of `unsigned char` that stores the scan code of keys: The index of the item is the key on my standard QWERTY keyboard, the value of the item is the scan code. This way, I can easily map the key on my QWERTY to its scan code so that I can work with the scan code.

```
mapKey['A'] = 30; //Key 'A' on QWERTY keyboard has scan code = 30
mapKey['B'] = 48;
mapKey['C'] = 46;
mapKey['D'] = 32;
mapKey['E'] = 18;
mapKey['F'] = 33;
mapKey['G'] = 34;
mapKey['H'] = 35;
mapKey['I'] = 23;
mapKey['J'] = 36;
mapKey['K'] = 37;
mapKey['L'] = 38;
mapKey['M'] = 50;
mapKey['N'] = 49;
mapKey['O'] = 24;
mapKey['P'] = 25;
mapKey['Q'] = 16;
mapKey['R'] = 19;
mapKey['S'] = 31;
mapKey['T'] = 20;
mapKey['U'] = 22;
mapKey['V'] = 47;
mapKey['W'] = 17;
mapKey['X'] = 45;
mapKey['Y'] = 21;
mapKey['Z'] = 44;
mapKey[VK_LEFT] = 75;
mapKey[VK_RIGHT] = 77;
mapKey[VK_RETURN] = 28;
... more if needed
```

Answer (score 0):

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48313645/1836776) here -- tl;dr: use `WM_CHAR`, not `MapVirtualKey`